# How can I find out in git which files are different between branches?

Tags: git

When I do

```
git commit -a
```

at the end a nice list of the files that have been modified since last commit is displayed.

Would it be possible to have a similar listing of the files that are different between different branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of files and number of lines changed at each file between different branches:

```
git diff --stat other_branch
```

To get a list of files changed since e.g. 3 commits back on the current branch

```
git diff --stat HEAD~3
```

on the other_branch

```
git diff --stat other_branch~3
```

To work between two branches

```
git diff --stat branchA branchB
```

In general you are working with commits so its perfectly legal to write

```
git diff --stat <commit_a> <commit_b>
```

where commit_a and commit_b are usual git commit descriptors.

It is possible to get stats on directories:

To get a list of directories and percentage of changes in each directory

```
git diff --dirstat <COMMIT>
```

which you can pretty much customize with different arguments ( changes, lines,files,...) e..g

```
git diff --dirstat=files other_branch
```